# DIV switch with active link and URL parameter

Tags: jquery, url

I’m trying to do div switch from URL parameter with active link. Six `<div>`s, six links; could be more, could be less.

I would like URL Parameters loading with active link switch, e.g. `page.html?option=c2`.
At the moment, loading correct content with URL parameter but without active link, `onclick` active thereafter working.

Opera having problems I think with wrap div.

Here’s my code so far:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var option = 'c1';
    var url = window.location.href;
    option = url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1];
    showDiv(option);    

    function showDiv(option) {
     $('#' + option).show();
    }   
$('#con1b a').click(
    function() {
    var showThis = $(this).attr('name');
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#wrap > div').hide();
    $('#' + showThis).show();
    return false;
    }); 
});
```

CSS is this

```
#con1b a.active {color:#ff3300; text-decoration: none;}
#wrap div {display: none;}
```

HTML is this

```
<div id="con1b">
<a href="javascript:showDiv('c1')" name="c1">Link C1</a>
<a href="javascript:showDiv('c2')" name="c2">Link C2</a>
<a href="javascript:showDiv('c3')" name="c3">Link C3</a>
<a href="javascript:showDiv('c4')" name="c4">Link C4</a>
<a href="javascript:showDiv('c5')" name="c5">Link C5</a>
<a href="javascript:showDiv('c6')" name="c6">Link C6</a>
```

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="c1">C1 Content</div>
    <div id="c2">C2 Content</div>
    <div id="c3">C3 Content</div>
    <div id="c4">C4 Content</div>
    <div id="c5">C5 Content</div>
    <div id="c6">C6 Content</div>
</div>
```

Example at
http://www.zest.ch/csi/2013/page.html?option=c2
Loads correct content for div without link as active (red).

Comment: Some pronouns are important sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

so far if i get you right you have two problems:

```
$('#wrap > div').hide();
```

this is not working in opera and you want to mark the link as active which i selected through the url parameter option=* ?

1.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="c1" class="con">C1 Content</div>
    <div id="c2" class="con">C2 Content</div>
    <div id="c3" class="con">C3 Content</div>
    <div id="c4" class="con">C4 Content</div>
    <div id="c5" class="con">C5 Content</div>
    <div id="c6" class="con">C6 Content</div>
</div>

$('#wrap div.con').hide()
```

will do. You also could go with

```
 $('#wrap').children('div').hide();
```

1. give your links an id and set the active.

   Link C1
   function showDiv(option) {
        $('#' + option).show();
        $('#l' + option).addClass('active');
   }
2. Just an enhancement:

   Link C1

should be replace by:

```
 <a class="linkme" name="c1">Link C1</a>

 $('.linkme').click(function() {
    var option = $(this).attr('name');
    showDiv(option);
 });
```

its not perfect but i hope you get what i mean

Another edit:
Sorry to say that BUT you cant use that in Opera 10.10 i just installed and checked it.
It seems to be a jquery (bug) problem. The error console just told me that it is not your code but the one from jquery.

Comment: thanks for the answer,  changed wrap div to both variations and show div option without enhancement, same behaviour as previously. Unfortunately getting towards midnight will have a look with enhancement tomorrow. Thank you Julian.

Comment: Super thanks till now, getting motivated, work in progress without 2. enhancement at [link](http://www.zest.ch/csi/2013/switch24b.html?option=c4)

Comment: Above link working how and where it should. Worked with children on wrap, without loaded fine but appended as stack other divs on top of each other onClick. Opera (am looking at 10.10) is ignoring the load active link colour. On Dom element inspection it loads #wrap as block, but is taking #wrap div as display none overwriting any subsequent values. Maybe a CSS issue and needs some full > path > referencing

Comment: Thanks Julian for the time and effort. I replied with a similar feeling to prodigitalson and have an idea where the cut off is. Some thinking for me this weekend and either Vanilla up (no active no url) or Jsq down with UA cut. Or fork it, two versions, but would have to write in this section in body and head section to avoid loading issues with page.html?option=xx e.t.c. mmm think about it still maybe less work than have done before. Have a good weekend and thanks. Chris

Comment: Everything works with jQuery 1.3.2 ( also min) Safari 3's, IOS 3, Opera down to 8.21x, FF cheked to 3.6.6 not chekced IE yet. Not much time to look at it further.

Comment: Ammended link can be found at [link](http://www.zest.ch/csi/2013/02/switch24b.html?option=c2)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/hK26Z/2/

First remove the name attribute as its unnecessary instead just us a class that applies to all the links you want to control the content hide/show. Also change the `href` to target the ID's directly, that way if a user doesnt have JS enabled for some god forsaken reason they will get the typical jump to behavior. Because we want it to degrade like this we wont hide the content with CSS - we will use jQuery's show and hide methods directly.

```
<div id="con1b">
    <a href="#c1" class="content-link">Link C1</a>
    <a href="#c2" class="content-link">Link C2</a>
    <a href="#c3" class="content-link">Link C3</a>
    <a href="#c4" class="content-link">Link C4</a>
    <a href="#c5" class="content-link">Link C5</a>
    <a href="#c6" class="content-link">Link C6</a>
</div>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="c1" class="content-container">C1 Content</div>
    <div id="c2" class="content-container">C2 Content</div>
    <div id="c3" class="content-container">C3 Content</div>
    <div id="c4" class="content-container">C4 Content</div>
    <div id="c5" class="content-container">C5 Content</div>
    <div id="c6" class="content-container">C6 Content</div>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$(function(){
  $('a.content-link').click(function (e) {
     var $this = $(this),
         containerSelector = $this.attr('href'),
         $links = $('a.content-link');

     e.preventDefault();

     // hide all content containers other than our target
     $('div.content-container').not(containerSelector).hide();

     // show the target
     $(containerSelector).show();

     // set active classes
     $links.not($this).toggleClass('active', false);
     $this.toggleClass('active', true);

  });

  // this runs on initialization to show our "active" content based on the url:
  (function(){
     var option = '#c1',
         url = window.location.href;

      option = '#' + url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1];

      // just fake a click on the element so the event handler runs
      $('a[href='+option+']').click();
  })();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea and doodle, have added an external link to show where I was at. Not too great with URL P,  what do I need to use for URL to sync content to link with the above? It's now approaching the bewitching hour and i will check again tomorrow, Thanks.

Comment: Content switching but no active link (also in Doodle), same Opera issue as with Julian Hille. Like i said I think I'm missing something with URl P, how would you access this with url p to set link as active?

Comment: I would jsut set an `active` class on it. The `:active` state isnt really much use for this type of thing. Updated code and fiddle.

Comment: Hey thanks for the time and update, if I get you correct this [link](http://www.zest.ch/csi/2013/switch25c.html?option=c4) is the ammended version. Which is now working the same as with Julian Hille above.

Comment: Not sure if the Opera issue is relating to finding out the css element from the top of the dom to switch content or if it is a case of pretty decent standard browsers - VS - partial/buggy ones. I asked this question and it's the first time am getting my hands dirty with the Jquery, originally was using some simple Vanilla JS which switched divs no problems but as you said rellied on the :active class giving certain browsers and users no clue of where they are. Having said that here [link](http://www.zest.ch/csi/2013/switch27b.html) is a JS method on toggle using e.style.display

Comment: It's pretty crude from the UI but switches and styles way down the Browser spectrum. Maybe I need to ask myself the hard question about UA cut off and future support. Unless there is a possibility to fork? Where do you define the Browser cut-off? I do know sometimes we do Local Government Print work and only last year I could trace from a fixed IP in the log file a department using NT IE6 which is almost about the same as the IE Mac 5.23.

Comment: Currently in all my projects i support IE8 - 10, Firefox Current plus a couple versions back, Safari Current, Chrome Current plus a couple versions back. Opera isn't considered nor are other Gecko/Webkit derivatives. And by support i mean the site will function and be usable, not that things will be 100% the same across browsers.

Comment: Well it now works down the UA spectrum with HEAD jQuery 1.3.2 (also min) not 1.9.1. Also works till Opera 9.6.4 that also means Safari 3's.